# how to normalize panda dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, neural-network, normalization

there is two panda dataframe . I used MinMaxScaler to normalize first dataframe in purpose of training a neural network . and for test dataset i need to do the same but how can I scale dataframe base on min and max of the first dataframe ? 
and because test data should not effect training , can not merge two dataframes , then scale and split again
datasets have a lot of columns 
example : 
first dataframe :

```
|     | colA |
| --- |---- |
| 1   | 3   |
| 2   | 10  |
| 3   | 4   |
| 4   | 0   |
```

second dataframe:

```
|     | colA |
| --- |--- |
| 1   | 2  |
| 2   | 5  |
```

expected scaling :

```
|     | colA |
| --- | --- |
| 1   | 0.2 |
| 2   | 0.5 |
```

Comment: What is the logic used in reaching to the expected result?

Comment: @NelsonGon i used first dataset min and max , then map second dataset base on them , 
its generally because i trained neural network base first dataset scaled in that range

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by map, I mean what numerical calculation did you perform?

Comment: @NelsonGon  newX = X− Xmin / ( Xmax−Xmin )  .  Xmin and Xmax comes from first  dataset  i.e Xmin = 0 , Xmax = 10

Comment: Could you share the data as a simple dict/pandas DataFrame that can be copied and pasted?

Comment: @NelsonGon example is simple . first  = {'col1': [3 , 10 , 4 , 0 ] }
second = {'col1': [2 , 5  ] } ; i used sklearn MinMaxScaler to scale first dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

train_df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [3, 10, 4, 0]})
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [2, 5]})

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(train_df)

train_df = scaler.transform(train_df)
test_df = scaler.transform(test_df)
```