# scaling and encoding with same technique at prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding, prediction, scaling

i used robustscaling and labelencoding for numerical and categorical column respectively at the time of training.

```
num_features = x_df[numeric_type]
scaler = RobustScaler()
x_df[numeric_type] = scaler.fit_transform(num_features.values)

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
x_df[categorical_type[i]] = label_encoder.fit_transform(x_df[categorical_type[i]])
```

and it works very fine.

and i trained my model also but when i try to give new values for prediction so i have to give value in the encoded aur scaled form

eg:
at training :
apple -> 1

at prediction: if i want to insert apple as a value so i want to type apple but this says you have to give 1
so any solution to encode with same technique as used in training with the sequence of variable also. means variable will user defined so i dont have idea of sequence of variable what user decided for training and prediction.
thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73262975/12363750

Comment: that solution only have numerical variable but in my case there are mix variable user can select any variable so my code should run according to the sequence